# Exporting GIMP image to pdf with specific page size

Tags: gimp, pdf, file-format

I need to use GIMP to generate a particular `.pdf` with a specific page size, namely, A1.

For this question, I did a minimal working example with A4 page size, since I believe the specific format doesn't matter.

I open GIMP, open the dialogue window for a new file, and I use the `Template` drop down menu to select `A4 (300 ppi)` and press enter.

If I do just that and export that new (blank A4) file to pdf, open said pdf and go see the properties, I'll see that the pdf's `Page size` is `Portrait A4`, with the correct dimensions (210x297 mm).

If I try to modify in any way the file before exporting to pdf, open said pdf and go see the properties, I'll see that the pdf's `Page size` is not A4, it's listed as `Portrait Custom` and the dimensions are way too big (875x1238 mm).

I don't see any options in the export to pdf dialogue option that allows me to get what I want (that is, a specific A4 pdf containing the image I desire).

Can someone help me ? Bellow are included the screenshot of my process :

Creating the new file :

[image]

The blank image I'm exporting :

[image]

The modified image I'm exporting :

[image]

The settings I used for both exports :

[image]

The properties for the blank PDF :

[image]

The properties for the modified PDF :

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately I can't replicate the problem, I just tried repeating your steps, but  both PDFs are the same size in physical dimensions.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks. My initial try was on Manjaro KDE, after reading you comment, I tried on Windows 10 and it works.

Comment: Yeah, I checked using Window 10, GIMP 2.10.12, checked PDF in Adobe Reader.  All seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly a bug.

When I repeat your steps, in the image print size (*Image>Print size*) the print definition has been reset to 72PPI (and since the size in pixels hasn't changed, this gives the strange print size).

Forcing the print definition back to 300PPI seems to fix it for good (doesn't change with later exports or edits).

PS: made a [bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/4324)